# One host, multiple Wordpress domains, one CiviCRM database

Tags: wordpress, settings, multisite

We want to use CiviCRM on one host which has several domains each with their own Wordpress  installation. The CiviCRM database is located on the same host.
I have looked at: 
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=86213708

but cannot figure out which scenario applies. 
Is there something else I should look at?

I think I want to put the CiviCRM plugin in the wp-content/plugins in each domain, but indicate the same CiviCRM database for each. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done multisite with Wordpress, but I think this link is more up-to-date documentation:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/#wordpress-multisites

> If using a WordPress multisite when CiviCRM is activated the civicrm.settings.php file is added within the uploads directory for that site. Site 1, generally the main site of the multisite, uses the default upload path /wp-content/uploads/. But all other sites will use be in /wp-content/uploads/sites/#/civicrm, the # being the website ID for that site. This default setup allows multiple CiviCRM databases to share one codebase...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a scenario with multiple website but one CiviCRM, and the websites communicating with CiviCRM using the API.
Some more information on this kind of scenario on 
https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external
and 
https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

i'm french, 
is it somes différents wordpress or a WPMU ? 
if it's diffrent wordpress, each files "civicrm.settings.php" need to b connected with your database in line "define('CIVICRM_DSN'"xxxxxxx)
if you use a WPMU, you cans set like the previous URL "wordpress-mulstisites".
Il use an other way that do the same thing.
best regards